# Doctrine2, DQL, association not initialized

Tags: doctrine-orm, initialization, associations, dql, bidirectional

is here some doctrine expert, who can explain me, why these DQLs will not initialize *tallyRevs* field on Tally entity? I supposed, that when I fetch TallyRevs (owner side) and fetchJoin Tally entity to them, that field *tallyRevs* will be initialized. What am I doing wrong? I need to select *TallyRev* based on some criteria via DQL and since it is a bi-directional association, I would like it to be initialized from the other (Tally.tallyRevs) side also.

[Screen of dump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIf5I.png)

```
<?php


/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="v3_overview_calloff_tally")
 */
class Tally
{

    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var TallyRev[]|Collection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="STI\Model\Entity\V3\Overview\CallOff\TallyRev", mappedBy="tally")
     */
    private $tallyRevs;
}


/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="v3_overview_calloff_tallyrev")
 */
class TallyRev
{

    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $revision;

    /**
     * @var Tally
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="STI\Model\Entity\V3\Overview\CallOff\Tally", inversedBy="tallyRevs")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="tally_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    private $tally;
}
```

Here is some repository code:

```
$qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder();
$qb
    ->select('tallyRev')
    ->from(TallyRev::class, 'tallyRev', 'tallyRev.id')
    // complicated filtering, this is just an example
    ->andWhere($qb->expr()->in('tallyRev.revision', ':rev'))
    ->setParameter('rev', $rev)
;
$tallyRevs = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();

$ids = array_keys($tallyRevs);

$qb2 = $repository->createQueryBuilder();
$qb2
    ->select('partial tallyRev.{id}')
    ->from(TallyRev::class, 'tallyRev', 'tallyRev.id')
    ->andWhere($qb2->expr()->in('tallyRev.id', ':ids'))
    ->setParameter('ids', $ids)
    ->leftJoin('tallyRev.tally', 'tally')
    ->addSelect('tally')
;
$qb2->getQuery()->getResult();
```

I know, that I can write DQL from the Tally side like this:

```
$qb
    ->select('tally')
    ->from(Tally::class, 'tally', 'tally.id')
    ->leftJoin('tally.tallyRev', 'tallyRev')
    ->addSelect('tallyRev')
    ->andWhere($qb->expr()->in('tallyRev.revision', ':rev'))
    ->setParameter('rev', $revs)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch join tally when you fetch tallyRev you should write something like this in the first qb, and delete qb2

```
->select(['tallyRev', 'tally'])
->from(TallyRev::class, 'tallyRev', 'tallyRev.id')
->join('tallyRev.tally', 'tally')
// complicated filtering, this is just an example
->andWhere($qb->expr()->in('tallyRev.revision', ':rev'))
->setParameter('rev', $rev)
```

;